# "socket.io.js" was blocked due to MIME type

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, mime-types

I'm trying to learn Socket.io but I can't make a working project because every one I make gets a MIME type mismatch.

ERROR:
The resource from “http://localhost:5500/socket.io/socket.io.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

To test this I found a working chat app project from Github and tested that code and got the same problem. That code can be found at: https://github.com/bradtraversy/chatcord

The code seems to correctly create a socket.io instance:

```
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

// Set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

...

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

The HTML connects the JS with the line:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

This MIME type message is followed by an "io is not defined" error in reference to the client code:

```
const socket = io();
```

This MIME type appears on Firefox but not on Chrome, it doesn't and only gives a 404 not found. I don't know if that's just a browser difference.

Comment: I checked out your repository, ran the code, and could not reproduce the problem. The error does not occur, the URL resolves to some JS. Maybe you forgot to restart the server after editing the code in. Maybe you need to clear the browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the browser cannot download the javascript file at `http://localhost:5500/socket.io/socket.io.js`. Consequently, the `io()` method isn't defined.

You can try load the file from CDN, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-installation/index.html). Replace

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

by :

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.3/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-cPwlPLvBTa3sKAgddT6krw0cJat7egBga3DJepJyrLl4Q9/5WLra3rrnMcyTyOnh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

**EDIT** :
I tried to reproduce your problem, but I cannot. So, I provide the maximum information of my environment for you to reproduce the result:

- I use the repository `chatcord` (clone and run `npm run dev`)
- My server runs on port 3000.
- My node version: v14.17.0
- My npm version: v7.13.0
- My system: Windows 10

The project works without any modification. When I tried to use socket.io from a CDN, I need to use the same version with the installed module on the server-side (^2.0.4 based on `package.json`)

Comment: This sounds the correct origin of the problem but it doesn't contain a real solution to it rather an avoidance strategy ;-) The question is right tho: Why doesn't the browser load `io` from `socket.io.js` ?

Comment: Yes, I went on the documentation page and it said that `By default, the Socket.IO server exposes a client bundle at /socket.io/socket.io.js.`. Honestly, I cannot find why it doesn't work here with the information in the question. Therefore, I try to provide an alternative solution (which is also from the documentation :) )

Comment: Switching to using the CDN (or copying the CDN files directly) results in a repeating failed GET request every few seconds:

GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Neg95ex
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]

Comment: It tries to connect to the server but it couldn't. Did you test it with the repository `chatcord` ?

Comment: Yes, that's the one I tested it with

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem but I cannot. I edited my answer providing the information of my environment, perhaps it will help you reproduce my result.